# Bootstrap 5 - Same height items inside different columns

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I have problem with items inside different columns. How can I make for ".item" equal height in both columns?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div class="item p-3 border mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis ratione enim consequatur.
      </div>
      <div class="item p-3 border mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis ratione enim consequatur.
      </div>
      <div class="item p-3 border mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div class="item p-3 border mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis ratione enim consequatur.
      </div>
      <div class="item p-3 border mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo.
      </div>
      <div class="item p-3 border mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis ratione enim consequatur.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Since the box-height is being decided by the content, I think it is only possible for large screens. You can add something like `min-height:200px` to the .item class in css. Do u always want both to be of equal height but with hidden overflow?

Comment: Yes, it will only display on large screens. Content of .item class box will be 20-180 characters. I don't like idea with min-height, it won't fit content to .item height. I would like to have same height of items in line but in diffrent columns, in second line it can be different height but the same for all items in line.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reply, your solution is ok but it will be loop in php:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <?php foreach( 6 items );?>
      <div class="item p-3 border mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis ratione enim consequatur.
      </div>
      <?php endforeach();?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <?php foreach( 3 items );?>
      <div class="item p-3 border mb-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis ratione enim consequatur.
      </div>
      <?php endforeach();?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I think the best solution will be use Javascript to make equal items. I just wanted to know is that possible to make it only with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I Think it can be solve only like that :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                             <h3>Title</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="item p-3 border h-100">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis
                                ratione enim consequatur.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="item p-3 border h-100">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis
                                ratione enim consequatur.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="item p-3 border h-100">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis
                                ratione enim consequatur.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="item p-3 border h-100">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <div class="item p-3 border h-100">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="item p-3 border h-100">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tempora deleniti aliquam assumenda modi, fugit. Harum, consequuntur, explicabo. Ab accusantium libero fugit nam vero aspernatur aperiam facilis
                                ratione enim consequatur.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you can use javascript for create equal height divs